# Lucene Deep Search in to Reference Object

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on Lucene for one of my projects and facing problem in implementing deep search in Lucene. I will explain my scenario.

I have following document structure:

```
{
   id: 1
   title: "This is Title",
   content: "This is the content of document",
   documentReference: 2
}

{
   id: 2
   title: "This is SAP",
   content: "This is the content of SAP"
}

{
   id: 3
   title: "This is Document 3",
   content: "This is the content of document 3",
   documentReference: 2
}
```

So, the document 1 (id 1) has reference of document 2 (id 2). Similarly, Document 3 (id 3) has again reference of document 2. It may possible that there is 10K+ document who are referring to Document 2.

I want to perform the search on the reference document also. There is one way that I can put the document 2 inside the document 1 and 3 and then index it so that Lucene will be able to search, but what if I change the content of document 2. In that case, I have to modify the index of document 1 and 3 too. Also if 10K document is referring to document 2, I have to reindex all 10K document, which will be a costly operation.

**So I want to perform the search on the reference object/document too.**

Also, In this example, the reference is in the same type of object, or in other word reference is in the same Lucene Index, it is also possible that the reference is in different Lucene Index.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what do you mean by **I want to perform the search on the reference document also** ? Why is that difficult? I guess, somewhere you are mixing up Lucene index & Lucene storage. Can you paste a sample about your possible queries & also if you are using .NET or Java?

Comment: yeah an example query would be nice. i don't see any usecase why you shouldn't search over all records without a specific query example.

Comment: Hi Sabir, Dom,

Thanks for your response, I am using Java, My basic requirement is "I want to know how to write a query so that it will search for the reference documents". For example in above document structure (JSON) If I search for "SAP" as free text search, I will get only "ID:2" as result, but as "ID:1" and "ID:3" both are using "ID:2" they should also come as result.

Comment: Not only in Lucene, If any one can help me in Elastic Search also, It will be great